# How can I post to posts and pages on a blogger blog using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, google-api, gdata, blogger

I am looking to automate some functionality on my blogger blogs and would like to use Ruby to do it.  What do I need to look into to post both blog posts and bogger.com's newer "Pages" feature?

Updated:

Based on quick googling it looks like there isn't really any complete libraries - GData for ruby looks incomplete with the Blogger API as a TODO.

A guess based on a quick review is that I have to Authenticate with the GData API and then use the authentication to communicate with Blogger's API.   There is an Atom API that some people have used with ruby but it is on the way to deprecation so it is probably a bad choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best choice is to use the Protocol API for Blogger and build up what you need around it.  This way you are able to use the latest features available in the API.  Unfortunately, there's no native Ruby wrapper for it, so you'll have to handle sending and receiving HTTP messages yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link but it uses vb .net. I think the basic mechanism is same.

http://www.karipap.com/Posting_Article_To_Blogger_Using_Visual_Basic_Net_Code.htm

Comment: Note: This website no longer exists.